# Is a specific timezone using DST right now?

Tags: python, time, timezone, pytz

How would I get my python script to check whether or not a specific timezone that is stored in a variable using DST right now?
My server is set to UTC.
So I have 
say for instance

```
zonename = Pacific/Wallis
```

I want to run the query about if it is using DST right now and have the reply come back as either true of false.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

zonename = "Pacific/Wallis"
now = datetime.now(tz=timezone(zonename))
dst_timedelta = now.dst()
### dst_timedelta is offset to the winter time, 
### thus timedelta(0) for winter time and timedelta(0, 3600) for DST; 
### it returns None if timezone is not set

print "DST" if dst_timedelta else "no DST"
```

alternative is to use:

```
now.timetuple().tm_isdst
```

Which can have one of 3 values: `0` for no DST, `1` for DST and `-1` for timezone not set.

Comment: my (independent) solution to [the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19774709/4279) is eerie similar (including variables names).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: *"There should be one— and preferably only one –obvious way to do it."* [PEP-20 aka The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) ;-)

Comment: that is why I love Python :)

Comment: How to distinguish tm_isdst=0 in case of a timezone currently not in DST, from the timezone that does not use DST at all?

In: datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).timetuple().tm_isdst
Out: 0

In: datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Australia/Melbourne')).timetuple().tm_isdst
Out: 0

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.9 has added the [zoneinfo module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) which replaces pytz. Here is a new updated version for modern Python versions.

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from datetime import datetime

bool(datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo("America/Chicago")).dst())
```