# Using Python standard library to get time offset for a given timezone

Tags: python

I'm trying to write an Alexa skill which requires me to calculate what the current time offset is (in minutes). I'm in New York, and the Alexa server has its time set at UTC. I need to know 1) is daylight savings currently active in Eastern time (this alone would actually be enough because I could then just hard code either 4 or 5 hours behind) 2) (would be nice) get the actual offset.

I found 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774709/use-python-to-find-out-if-a-timezone-currently-in-daylight-savings-time) question, but it uses pytz, which Alexa does not allow to be imported, so I need a solution that only uses the standard library. The second answer in the linked question seems like it may be what I'm looking for, but I don't understand it and am not sure if it's what I'm looking for. I would like to just be able to pass in something like "America/New York" and either get back -240 or -300 depending on the time of year. Thanks.

Comment: I just checked if the second answer from the above linked question works; it does not, because time.tzset() is only available on UNIX. I should add that I'm testing on WIndows, but perhaps AWS Lambda runs Unix??

Comment: Update: It works on AWS Lambda, so my problem is essentially solved.