# How do I determine whether I am within daylight savings time or not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dst, pytz

I have code that I've put together to identify the exact hour the daylight savings time starts and when it ends. The problem is that I can't catch everything between those particular hours, on those dates, and say that yes it is within daylight savings time. My code for detecting the hours is as follows:

```
def getDaylightSavings(date, hourEnding):

    #  daylight saving's time switches
    #print date.month, date.isoweekday(), date.day, hourEnding
    if (date.month == 3 and date.isoweekday() == 7 and (date.day >= 8 and date.day <= 14) and hourEnding == 3): return 1
    if (date.month == 11 and date.isoweekday() == 7 and (date.day >= 1 and date.day <= 7) and hourEnding == 3): return 2
```

This way I know what time adjustments to use. The problem is that if the time I pass into the function is `3/11/2018 4:00:00` it won't return as daylight savings whereas `3/11/2018 3:00:00` will be detected.

Is there a library I can use for determining daylight savings or something I can do here code-wise that will help?

This question is not a duplicate because I need to determine whether daylight savings time is in effect for any arbitrary time. Please help.

Comment: You want the `pytz` library.

Comment: `pytz` is in utc. The comment above about using the `time` module seems promising but the problem is that it's not clear how I can use it for a datetime like `u'2018-04-29T23:00:00'`

Comment: ahh, the perks of working with times..

Comment: A time string like `u'2018-04-29T23:00:00'` should be treated with caution. It has no timezone info, so you need to be certain about whether it's a local time, or a UTC time. And if it's local, make sure it's from your locality. ;)

Comment: You may find jfs's answer here to be what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19968515/4014959 He has a version that only uses stdlib modules. Unfortunately, it only tells you if DST is in effect now, not at an arbitrary time.

Comment: That's not what I need. I need to determine whether daylight savings time is in effect or not.

Comment: When you have a datetime like that without any other meta information *you are screwed*, in the same way as when you try to open a text file without knowing its encoding. You can take some guesses, but you can be wrong.

Comment: I don’t see why this is any different from those other questions. You take a time zone and a `datetime`, call the `.dst()` method and you have your answer.

Comment: If you can make it happen then by all means post an answer... it's not that easy.