# How to find out if DST was effective for some date in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst

I have following data: geographical coordinates of the place and local date and time, not necessarily current, may point to some moment many years ago. I also may have non-DST time zone effective currently, at present time (but  not necessarily correct for the date and time of interest). 
I want to find out whether DST was in effect in that location at that local time using Python. Any ideas how to do that? I was reading about package pytz, but could not find anything suitable in it to complete that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've already resolved the time zone itself - if not, there are really two problems in this one question:

- Finding a time zone ID from coordinates
- Determining if DST was in effect in a time zone at an arbitrary date/time

I'm not very familiar with Python, but given [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=tzinfo#datetime.tzinfo) I believe you want the `tzinfo.dst(dt)` function, which will return `timedelta(0)` in standard time, and the difference between the standard offset and the wall offset in DST. You pass in the `datetime` you want to find the offset for.

Note that in the `pytz` library, there's an additional `is_dst` parameter which you can specify to resolve ambiguities, where a given local time occurs twice due to a "fall back" transition.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need one of the solutions in [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates) to identify the timezone that the given coordinates belongs to.

Once you have the timezone you can then use the solution at [Is a specific timezone using DST right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173298/is-a-specific-timezone-using-dst-right-now) to determine if DST is effective given the timezone and the date/time.