# Conflicting localized datetime object for same timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst, pytz

I am getting two different time offset using US/Eastern pytz timezone.

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
    import datetime
    
    tz = timezone('US/Eastern')

>>> tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 1, 21, 1, 0))

2021-11-01 21:01:00-04:00

>>> tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 21, 1, 0))

2020-11-01 21:01:00-05:00
```

Why am I getting different time offsets for the same timezones?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Put is as answer and I'll be accepting it,

Comment: you may also want to read [the `timezone` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section titled "Time Zone != Offset"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[US/Eastern timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) switch to standard/winter time in first Sunday of November.
Which in 2020 was 1 November 2020, and in 2021 was 7 November 2021
i.e. on 1 November 2021 DST was still on.

You can check [Is a specific timezone using DST right now?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17173298/4046632) on how to check if DST is on.